# Finding the vector field obtained by the parallel transport along a given curve

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-fields

I'm trying to do some exercises of my book to better understand the concept of parallel transport.

Excercise: Consider the affine connection on $\mathbb{R^2}$ defined by the Christoffel symbols $\Gamma^i_ {j,k} = 2 $ if $i=j=k=2 $, $\Gamma^i_ {j,k} = 0$ otherwise and the curve:

$\sigma: \mathbb{ R} \rightarrow \mathbb{ R^2}$

$ t \rightarrow (e^{-4t}+5, 3t+7) $

Find the vector field given by the parallel transport along the curve $\sigma$ of its tangent vector $\sigma(2)$.

There are no numeric examples on my book and I can't understand what should I do to solve this excercise. It's marked as an easy exercise, but I'm really lost.

Edit: my problem is that I don't understand how to include in that ODE $\sigma (2)$. I have computed that $y^1 = const$ and $y^2 = e^{6t}/6 + const$. But I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Are we assuming the standard coordinate system on $\Bbb R^2$? As it stands, the problem is not complete. It is also badly phrased. I assume you (they?) mean the tangent vector to $\sigma$ at $t=2$? What is written makes no sense. At any rate, you use that as the initial conditions in your differential equations for $y^i$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: In your book you probably have the ODE for the parallel transported vector $y(t)$:
$$ \dot{y}^i + \Gamma^i_{jk} \dot{\sigma}^j y^k = 0 . $$
This takes a particular simple form in your example.